# Adding to or deleting from a displayed list and redisplaying list in a particular div

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

For my first ASP.NET MVC 3 application I have a `div` on a partial view that displays a list of proposed names for a particular ice cream.  I'm using, as my first crack at this, something like this to display the proposed names:

```
@model ViewModels.IceCream.{ProposedNamesViewModel
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Proposed Names</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach (var item in Model.ProposedNames)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>
         @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
      </td>
      <td>
         @item.ProposedName
      </td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

and this works fine enough for displaying those names.  These proposed names are but but one of a number of pieces of information about the selected ice cream and what I'd like to accomplish is to allow the user to add or delete a name and then have as a result of one of those actions have the updated viewmodel's data re-displayed in that div (i.e., leaving everything else as it is on the page and just replacing that div's contents with the new contents.

I can write the controller's delete action just fine and it will update the underlying DB but then I'm not sure how to return this `PartialView` back to the particular `div` with my updated viewmodel.  I hope that makes sense.

This (likely web developer 101) concept is one that I haven't grokked yet and I'm hoping someone can show me how to do this.

---

**Update**

I'm looking at using jquery to solve this.  Stephan Prodan (I believe that's his name) has an example [here](http://www.stefanprodan.eu/2011/04/async-operations-with-jquery-ajax-and-asp-net-mvc/) where he updates a list of notes using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery is definitely a good direction to go with this. The only modification I would suggest to your table for a jQuery solution would be to add an index to each < tr > tag (unique for each row, preferably one based off the item displayed in the row). Then the rest is javascript. Bind a click event to the delete option, and on the delete, one jQuery line will do your job:

```
$("#" + rowID).remove()
```

As far as adding new rows, simply generate a string representing it:

```
var newrow = "<tr id='newrowID'><td>Delete</td><td>proposedname</td></tr>
```

And (now I realize you might want to add an id to your < table > as well if you have more than one on your page) then add it to the table with

```
$("#" + tableID).append(newrow)
```

or

```
$('table').first().append(newrow)
```

if it's your first table on your page and you don't want to give it an id.

Lastly, you would need an AJAX call to get the information for the new item (or to send it to the backend if you create it on the page).

**EDIT**:
Suggested AJAX call:

```
//disable input here
$.ajax({
    url: "myurl/delete/" + idemID,
    success: function(response){
                       if(successful){ //determine this based on response
                                $("#" + rowID).remove()
                                //re-enable input
                        }
    error: function(err){ alert("Something went wrong"); /*re-enable input*/}
})
```

The disabling of the input prevents the user from providing multiple sucessive calls to the db that might conflict with each other or otherwise cause problems.

Comment: Thanks Jim - I'm mulling over what you wrote.  I guess the .remove() part is just updating the html and then your last line there that you wrote is the part where a call needs to be made to send the delete back to the controller action to update the underlying DB.  So in your example, the UI is being updated in the jQuery rather than by re-rendering the list of proposed names, right?

Comment: Exactly. One thing you want to consider though, that I forgot to account for when I wrote this answer, is that the user may provide input in rapid succession (keep clicking deletes, or something else your page includes). So it might be best to disable input while you wait for the backend to respond to your delete call. Maybe even remove the row after you get the response.

Answer (score 1):

You could use MVC's Ajax helpers, but I feel they're a bit clunky at times. It also seems like they're designed for forms versus your table implementation. If you can use something javascripty like jQuery, you can give yourself a lot more flexibility albeit a bit more code. I'll show you what I consider the Microsoft way below. Maybe I'll try to modify it to use jQuery to illustrate the differences.

### Ajax helpers

If you're using MVC 3, be sure to have jQuery and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax referenced for the following example, as that's most likely configured in web.config

Here is the primary view

```
<div id="myTableContainer">
@{Html.RenderPartial("GetTable", new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" });}
</div>
```

And my strongly typed (`List<string>`) partial view. Yours would be typed to your view model

```
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model) { 
        <tr>
        <td>@item</td>
        <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "GetTable", new { id = item }, 
                new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myTableContainer" })</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

And, finally, the controller action that returns the partial view

```
public ActionResult GetTable(string id)
{
    // you would obviously create your list of your ice cream objects here
    // get them from a service/repository and build a view model
    List<string> list = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        list.Remove(id);

    return View("GetTable", list);
}
```

This is a crude demonstration, but it should give an idea of how the Ajax helpers work to re-render views.

Comment: I'll go google it but I guess "UpdateTargetId" in your AjaxOptions calls out the "target" id for the view returned, right?  I think that's the part that has been the disconnect.  There's nothing in the controller's action itself that "knows" where it's going to be rendered, it just returns the appropriate view and I guess that AjaxOption specifies that the particular div named "myTableContainer" is where the view will be put, right?

Comment: And I guess what it's actually doing there is replacing the contents of that div with the contents of the partialview, right?

Comment: @itsmatt You got it--it's a bit clunky because user input postbacks requires something static (generating unique `Ajax.ActionLink`'s) on render. Using jQuery, the postback data could be generated client side and you could even grab more data to customize your post.